# my website can no longer send email and I didn't even change the code

Tags: email, spf, dkim

After receiving reports from my website assistant that he was unable to receive email resulting from a user performing an action that would generate an email to him, I decided to test a function on my site that worked in the past. I used the simple contact form to try to send an email to myself and my website assistant. Instead of the email going out, the remote servers rejected the email. When I looked in the server logs, I see this error reported from the yahoo server (into my exim_mainlog file)

"SMTP error from remote mail server after end of data: 554 5.7.9 Message not accepted for policy reasons."

I checked the account settings on my server through cpanel and

noticed that DKIM and SPF are enabled on the account.

Next to SPF, I see  "(v=spf1 +a +mx +ip4:64.15.69.254 ~all)"

Is it possible that I need to modify that SPF string to make the remote mail clients happy? I'm using WHM 11.52.2 build 5 and something makes me thing upgrading is a solution but at the same time, upgrading could wreck other parts of my high-speed website setup.

So without upgrading can I fix this problem? Does it really boil down to just a data configuration error that magically happened?

Comment: Sorry but question is not unique, as "Message not accepted for policy reasons" is a spam trigger and if you can't find a relevant answer in the post linked, its because someone hasn't left one yet... you can perform a quality edit to bump old posts, or run bounties on other people's questions to improve, or receive more current answers. Additionally, most email providers that block emails have reasons listed why on their website, for example... for Yahoo... you should use DKIM (Domain-Keys Identified Mail)
SPF and DMARC. Feel free to ask in our chat channel for more tailored responses.

Comment: It's most likely because they have made their spam trigger more strict... your domain fails DMARC https://mxtoolbox.com/problem/dmarc/dmarc-record?page=prob_dmarc&action=dmarc:clubcatcher.com&showlogin=1&hidepitch=0&hidetoc=1 (click of the box)... so Yahoo mails will likely fail sometimes!